# What is the most efficient way to perform a range query over a cluster of nodes?

Tags: range

What is the most efficient way to perform a range query over a cluster of nodes where I want the result sets merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is too vague: the terms "range", "cluster", and "nodes" can be applied to just too many different things. Please be more specific.